# Data Modelling - SVM

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am currently doing Data modelling and I am getting an error and couldn't find a solution to it. So I am hoping I would get some help from this platform! 
Thanks in advance.

My code:-

```
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn import svm

X = np.array(observables) #X are features
y = np.array(df['diagnosis']) # y is label

X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test= cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

clf= svm.SVC()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
accuracy= clf.score(X_test, y_test)
print (accuracy)
```

However I get this error:

> ValueError: bad input shape (114, 8)

Comment: please show `print(X.shape)` and `print(y.shape)`

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you mixed up the order of the [return values of `train_test_split`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html), use

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test= cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
```

instead of

```
X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test= cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
```

Comment: At first i thought: why the hell he is linking some deprecated-function (as the link shows), but then i realized it's the doc of the stable-branch and it follows the original usage in the question. Good answer!